Let's get critical: Dec 2013 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Cryptography Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

Why is sharing the seed and using SecureRandom "deterministically" so bad?

Net Score: 8 (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)


Are there any differences in operation between existing Diffie-Hellman specifications?

Net Score: 5 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)


Diffie-Hellman Secret Exponent Size and Shared Secret Usage

Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)


Serpent cipher : Osvik S-Boxes confusion and test vectors

Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)


Blinding twice in RSA

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)


Why don't we use MACs to store passwords?

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)


Is the following aggregation scheme private?

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)


Homomorphic (encrypted) comparison to an integer

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)


Why send a challenge with CHAP?

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)


Hypothetical unknown cipher - security in obscurity?

Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)


median: 3, mean: 3, stddev: 2.582, per Wolfram|Alpha.

I haven't finished making my way through the list (what with it being Christmas and all that!) but in most cases these seem like pretty decent answers, and each one I've tried has been the best answer available on google.
Hopefully I'll have time to get through the rest and write up something useful (sorry if not!).
